# How does the temp HP from the Conjuration wizard's Durable Summons feature interact with the Find Familiar spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, familiars, temporary-hit-points

The description of the [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell states (emphasis mine):

> You gain the service of a familiar, a **spirit** that takes an animal form you choose. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> As an action, you can temporarily dismiss your familiar. It disappears into a pocket dimension where it awaits your **summons**. Alternatively, you can dismiss it forever. As an action while it is temporarily dismissed, you can cause it to reappear in any unoccupied space within 30 feet of you.

At 14th level, [School of Conjuration wizards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofConjuration) get the feature [Durable Summons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#DurableSummons-424):

> Starting at 14th level, any creature that you summon or create with a conjuration spell has 30 temporary hit points.

And the rules for [temporary hit points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints) state, in part (emphasis mine):

> Unless a feature that grants **you** temporary hit points has a duration, they last until they're depleted or **you** finish a long rest.

I'm not quoting the whole thing, but the description is written from the perspective of the creature that has the temp hit points, referring to that creature as "you" and "your".

Say a 14th-level Conjuration wizard casts *find familiar*. Since it is a conjuration spell, the familiar would get 30 temporary hit points. **But how long do these temporary hit points last?**

The description for THP says that if the feature that granted the THP has a duration (which it does not), they last until depleted; otherwise, the temporary hit points last until "you" finish a long rest. In this case, "you" is the familiar, and since the familiar is a spirit, it technically should not need a long rest. Therefore, it would last until depleted, correct?

Likewise, the feature says, "any creature that you summon". While the spell states that the familiar, if dismissed, waits in a pocket dimension for "your summons." **Would this mean that every time you bring the familiar back from its pocket dimension, it gets a fresh batch of 30 THP?** (And yes, I get there is more than one definition of "summon".)

I'm curious how to rule these situations.

Comment: How I long for the days where differences between summoning and conjuring were clearly defined.

Answer (score 6):

#### The temp HP are generated upon every summoning, and last until depleted or otherwise until the familiar finishes a long rest.

You've quoted all of the relevant rules in the OP. When you receive temporary HP, they last until they are depleted, or otherwise until you have finished a long rest. There's no reason to believe that your familiar doesn't require long rests (they use the stat block of an ordinary animal), so they last until they're depleted or until the familiar finishes a long rest.

They would receive these temporary HP whenever the *Find Familiar* spell is initially cast to summon them, as well as whenever you use an action to resummon them after temporarily dismissing them (since that's an ability granted by a conjuration spell).

Comment: Minor correction: the temp HP last until *the familiar* takes a long rest. The "you" in the temp HP rules refers to the creature that receives the temp HP.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Yes, but I think it's reasonable to assume that the familiar will time its long rests with those of its master.

Comment: Not necessarily. It might be prudent to have an owl familiar keep watch overnight and then take a long rest during the day, for example.

Answer (score 5):

### When you cast *find familiar*, the familiar starts with some temporary HP

[*Find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) does "summon or create" a familiar for you, so when the casting is complete, your new familiar should have a nice supply of temporary HP.

But no, the action to call your familiar out of its pocket dimension would not recharge it. That isn't *casting a spell to summon a creature*; it's just an action you have by the nature of familiars.

The text of the spell does not claim that calling the familiar out of its pocket is *summoning*. The phrase it uses is "you can cause it to reappear". It merely says the familiar "awaits your summons", as in the standard english meaning of the phrase -- waiting to be called into service.

Remember that the [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell has a duration of "Instantaneous", so even if the spell effect (the familiar) grants you an action you can use later, using that action is not casting a spell, and it's not occurring during the duration of a spell you previously cast. I don't see any way it would count for this purpose.

The Durable Summons feature is about creatures you create or summon with a spell, not about popping your familiar in and out of its extradimensional pet carrier.

### The temporary HP last until the familiar rests.

The "you" in the temporary HP rules refers to *the creature that has temporary HP*.  The familiar's temporary HP last until the familiar itself takes a long rest, regardless of what you, the caster, do.

Comment: The ability doesn't say you have to *cast* a Conjuration spell for the creatures to get the temp HP; they just have to be summoned or created by one. For instance, if you cast a hypothetical spell that created a spawn point that summoned a new creature each round it was active, all of the creatures so summoned would gain the temp HP.

Comment: I don't think summoning the familiar from its pocket dimension is really a part of the spell, more a feature of the familiar. If I use a spell to summon a horse, then later use a whistle to "summon" it from nearby, that's not using the spell to summon it.

Comment: @nick012000 I started to write a response but realized that it should be part of my answer, so now it is. But as Paul says, "summon" has a standard english meaning in addition to a D&D magical-creature-making meaning. Conjurers can't, say, give temporary HP by delivering court documents even if they do it by means of magic.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym If your court summons uses a conjuration spell and teleports them to the court, it would.